# Decode JSON RPC result

Tags: json-rpc

How do I convert the result returned from a JSON-RPC `eth_call` from my geth client?

This is the call:
`curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to":"0x86312d97c0dd3fd9202fdbdec434f36ee1b30720", "data":"0x18160ddd"}, "latest"],"id":1}' 127.0.0.1:8545`

This is the return:
`{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240"}`

How to convert:
`0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240` back to human readable characters?

Comment: use toasci funtion

Comment: I've tried `web3.toAscii("0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240")` and this is what I get: `"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0fB@"`

Comment: it depends on the return of your function toasci will work only if it return a string

Comment: Yes! that is the answer. Trivial actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its Hex encoded string you can convert it in to Decimal.

For web3:
web3.toDecimal('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240')

For javascript:
parseInt('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240', 16);

For PHP:
hexdec('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f4240');

// result: 1000000

For other programming languages you can search for hextodecimal function for that particular programming language.

Comment: Sometimes one needs to use bignumber.js - I've received the following result `2e+21` which wouldn't work with the functions above, would only work with `BigNumber(2e+21).toString(10)`